# Namespace management with ip netns (iproute2)

Tags: dnsmasq, iproute, namespace, hostapd

I would like to know where to look up changes applied to custom namespaces. Let's say I have a namespace "ns1" with virtual interfaces "vpeer" and "lo" inside and I would like to modify configurations of interface "vpeer" via dnsmasq or hostapd then I know that I am able to do so with e.g.

```
$ ip netns exec ns1 bash
$ dnsmasq --interface=vpeer-ns1 --dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.200,255.255.255.0
```

and netns is doing the rest of the job by mounting it for me and manage any assignments, which I am thankful for. However, in global namespace I could monitor changes made in corresponding files or apply them directly in a file. For example in **/etc/dnsmasq.conf** or **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**.

So my question is, how can I copy default namespace behaviour within a certain netns namespace. I really need to know what I have already done and what is the current configuration of the interfaces in "ns1". Not least because most tutorials explain procedures like this. The [ip netns man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) says that configuration files are located in

```
$ /etc/netns/ns1/
```

but not even the directory /etc/netns does exist after creation of namespace "ns1". The new namespace is only represented in /var/run/netns/ns1. This file is always empty - even after applying dnsmasq commands as above - and nano shows up with the empty file but gives me some strange error afterwards when file is closed saying that

```
ns1: Argument is invalid.
```

So I switched to namespace "ns1" and tried again. Same result. So I turned every device in the new namespace down with

```
$ ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev lo down
$ ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev vpeer down
```

Again, same result.

So how can I access configrations **files** with respect to a given namespace, since afaik the applications are not aware of the non-default namespace at all? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12):

You have two questions in one:

- what are the empty files in `/var/run/netns/`?
- how to use `/etc/netns/` which doesn't even exist?

### What are the empty files in `/var/run/netns/`?

Some understanding of [namespaces](https://manpages.debian.org/namespaces.7.en.html) is needed. I can't explain it in detail here. Suffice to say that a namespace once created will (partition some kernel resource such as network, and) exist as long as something is using it. Mostly two thing will use it: processes, or mountpoints in the special pseudo-filesystem `nsfs`. Once they stop using it or disappear, the namespace also disappears.

`ip netns` (which specializes in *network* namespaces) chooses to keep network namespaces by mounting a reference to them. Those references are all avalable in `/proc/<pid>/net/` as symlinks. Example:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/ns/net
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 0 Sep 25 01:05 /proc/19120/ns/net -> net:[4026531992]
$ stat -L -f -c %T /proc/19120/ns/net # filesystem type. "df" on this would be confused and point to the wrong mountpoint anyway.
nsfs
$ stat -L -c %i /proc/19120/ns/net # inode
4026531992
```

`ip netns add` just bind-mounts them in `/var/run/netns/<NAME>`. Note that while you usually bind-mount a directory over a directory, you can also bind-mount a file over a file. Note also that this file is a pseudo-file in the `nsfs` filesystem. It's not designed to be read, and can't be. It's mostly used to be passed around as a reference, by opening (but not reading or writing) it or mounting it:

```
# strace -e unshare,mount  ip netns add ns1
mount("", "/var/run/netns", 0x5625f6ca80e3, MS_REC|MS_SHARED, NULL) = 0
unshare(CLONE_NEWNET)                   = 0
mount("/proc/self/ns/net", "/var/run/netns/ns1", 0x5625f6ca80e3, MS_BIND, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
# ip netns list
ns1
# ls -l /var/run/netns/ns1
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 25 01:08 /var/run/netns/ns1
# cat /var/run/netns/ns1
cat: /var/run/netns/ns1: Invalid argument
# stat -f -c %T /var/run/netns/ns1
nsfs
# stat -c %i /var/run/netns/ns1
4026532824
# ip netns exec ns1 sleep 99 &
[1] 19620
# ls -l /proc/19620/ns/net
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep 25 01:23 /proc/19620/ns/net -> net:[4026532824]
```

So `sleep 99`'s network namespace is the one from the mountpoint `/var/run/netns/ns1`.
With this method, for example, it's possible to have a network namespace with a bridge linked to other namespaces with `veth` interfaces and not running any process, because none are needed.

You can manually delete namespaces created by `ip netns` with:

```
# umount /var/run/netns/ns1 
# rm /var/run/netns/ns1
# ip netns list
#
```

Of course the network namespace will really only disappear once the last reference using it (eg: process) will also disappear. You could even put it back, if the previous sleep command is still running:

```
# touch /var/run/netns/ns1
# mount --bind /proc/19620/ns/net /var/run/netns/ns1
# ip netns
ns1
```

This can be used to "copy" the network namespace's part of a full container, you just need to know some pid on the host side (eg: `lxc-info -Hp -n container` or `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' container`) and mount its network namespace. Handy to run debug commands not available inside the container (`tcpdump` ...).

Everything above is ephemeral, eg it disappears after a reboot.

### How to use `/etc/netns/` which doesn't even exist?

The [`ip netns` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/ip-netns.8.en.html) tells (bold emphasis mine):

> **For applications that are aware of network namespaces**, the convention
>   is to look for global network configuration files first in
>   `/etc/netns/`NAME/ then in `/etc/`. For example, if you want a different
>   version of `/etc/resolv.conf` for a network namespace used to isolate
>   your vpn you would name it `/etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf`.

Now, is `dnsmasq` "aware" of network namespaces? If it was (with `ip netns`'s definition) it would check for `/etc/netns/` somehow. There's no mention of "netns" in [its manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/dnsmasq.8.en.html). The current Debian's (similar to Raspberry's) source doesn't include the word `netns` anywhere: it's not network namespace aware.

That's why `ip netns` manpage's following sentence tells:

> `ip netns exec` automates handling of this configuration, file
>   convention **for network namespace unaware applications**, by creating a
>   mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace
>   configure files into their traditional location in `/etc`.

It's not really explained, but together with the previous sentence this really means that `ip netns exec` will bind-mount, *if both the source and target exist*, `/etc/netns/<NAME>/whatever` on `/etc/whatever`. `/etc/netns` and the chosen network namespace names inside,  which will contain the configurations *have to be created first, manually, and actual configuration content probably copied inside and edited*: `ip netns exec` will use them if found, but not create them.

Example:

```
# mkdir -p /etc/netns/ns1
# echo something > /etc/netns/ns1/whatever
# : > /etc/whatever
# ip netns add ns1
# cat /etc/whatever
# ip netns exec ns1 cat /etc/whatever
something
```

What really happened behind:

```
# strace -e open,unshare,setns,mount,umount2 ip netns exec ns1 cat /etc/whatever 2>&1 |egrep '^(open.*/etc/netns|unshare|setns|mount|umount|something)'
setns(5, CLONE_NEWNET)                  = 0
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)                    = 0
mount("", "/", 0x55947eb550e3, MS_REC|MS_SLAVE, NULL) = 0
umount2("/sys", MNT_DETACH)             = 0
mount("ns1", "/sys", "sysfs", 0, NULL)  = 0
open("/etc/netns/ns1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
mount("/etc/netns/ns1/whatever", "/etc/whatever", 0x55947eb550e3, MS_BIND, NULL) = 0
something
```

Of course this works the same for directories inside `/etc/netns/ns1` instead of files: the whole directory will appear directly in `/etc/` masking the host's directory of the same name, only if it exists.

So if dnsmasq's default configuration unless told otherwise is `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, You can create an alternate configuration for `ns1` as `/etc/netns/ns1/dnsmasq.conf` and `ip netns exec` will make it appear as `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to `dnsmasq`, *if* there's also already a `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file, even if it was empty. Since it's in `/etc` this isn't ephemeral and will be reused whenever you're recreating the same network namspace name. Same for `hostapd` and the whole `/etc/hostapd/` directory which can be copied as `/etc/netns/ns1/hostapd/` and its files then modified inside. Be careful with symlinks pointing outside. You can now run the commands as usual inside `ip netns exec ns1`: they'll use the new configuration file.