# Firejail not working over socks5 SSH tunnel

Tags: shell, ssh, networking, firejail, socks5-proxy

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server in which I've created two virtual interface pairs (veth0a & veth0b) and assigned the end of one interface (veth0b) to a new network namespace (netns0):

```
ip netns add netns0
ip netns exec netns0 ip link set lo up
ip link add veth0a type veth peer name veth0b
ip link set veth0b netns netns0
```

I then used firejail to force a specific user (test-user) to use this new namespace by default by setting `/usr/bin/firejail` as the default shell for this user and by adding the following to the `/etc/firejail/login.users` file:

```
test-user: --netns=netns0
```

I've ran the following test to make sure this works:

1. Run `tshark -i veth0a -f "port 443"` from the root account
2. SSH into the server as test-user
3. Run `curl https://1.1.1.1` as SSH user

The tshark output shows the proper veth0b source IP address for the 1.1.1.1 traffic.

The issue I'm running into is when trying to use the test-user account to establish socks5 dynamic port forwarding over SSH:

```
ssh -D 10000 -q -C -N test-user@server_ip
```

Running this command from my laptop or workstation allows me to establish a local socks5 server on port 1000 and tunnel it over the SSH connection. Setting this as my local socks5 proxy and going to `https://api.ipify.org` demonstrates that the proxy is working and that my laptop is using the server's IP address.

The issue is that the sock5 traffic does not appear to be going through the proper namespace. In other words, while browsing the web on my laptop while connected to the socks5 server over the test-user ssh connection my traffic does not appear in tshark -i veth0a.

Is there an additional step needed to ensure the port forwarding tunnel also uses firejail? Does setting the shell in /etc/passwd only impact an interactive login shell? Do i need to also change the user's non-interactive shell to `/usr/bin/firejail`? If so how would I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're attempting can't work and I'm explaining why.

Your ssh connection connects to the remote server's *sshd* daemon, which is running on the host, not the network namespace. There an instance is created for your connection. Then you're authenticated, then tunnels are setup, **then** your user session is setup.

Here's an excerpt from an example run with an ssh client version 7.9p1 using `ssh -v -4 -D 10000 remoteuser@server`:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server ([192.0.2.2]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:10000 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 10000.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 1: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
```

As you can see, `Local connections to LOCALHOST:10000 forwarded to remote address socks:0` ... `channel 0: new [port listener]` happens first. **Then**  `Entering interactive session` happens. This would normally call *firejail* etc., and it would be too late: whatever is done before happens on the host network namespace. But actually in your case, since you're using `-N`:

> `-N` Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.

no shell is ever run, *firejail* is not run and no alternate network namespace is ever touched. This wouldn't matter anyway even without `-N` as explained above.

So if you really want to do that, you'll need a separate SOCKS5 proxy, and you can't use the `-D` option anymore. You can run an instance of *sshd* or any other SOCKS5-able tool (eg: [`dante-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/dante-server)) inside the network namespace and do port redirections, using *iptable*, *nftables*, or the classic `-L` option of *ssh* to redirect to *veth0b*'s IP and this SOCKS5 proxy's listening port, but this will probably require more than just *firejail* and a normal user. At this point you'd better run the whole setup from *systemd*, or with a full-blown [*LXC*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lxc) (or *LXD* or *Docker* etc.) container. `ip netns` features are even often sufficient for this (see: [Namespace management with ip netns (iproute2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471122/namespace-management-with-ip-netns-iproute2/471214#471214)).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and explains exactly why what I'm attempting is not working. With that said is it possible to call firejail at authentication or to force all traffic for a specific user to always go through a specific network namespace?

Comment: You never explained what's your goal. You present what you want to do, but don't tell why you want this. You want to isolate a user, *and* what this user is allowed to do with tunnels from remote? But why?

Comment: My goal is to have multiple users use this SSH server as a socks5 proxy using dynamic port forwarding. Each user would be assigned a different network namespace which would allow me to monitor and log network traffic for each user separately.

Comment: You should forget about firejail and use an other method to log socks activity. Even sshd itself when set to loglevel DEBUG will log forwarded ports.

Comment: I am currently using tshark to log traffic which works well. For example if I monitor one end of the veth pair with tshark it gives me all traffic from within the namespace. Firejail aside I guess my question is: is it possible to assign each user with their own default network namespace so that all traffic for a given user always goes through that namespace?

Comment: You can ask this in a new question then. Somebody will perhaps be able to find an answer. The role of comments isn't to ask and answer new questions. Just remember you know why this doesn't work for ssh tunnels, so define precisely in the new question what is a user. By default it's a local user, but you'd like it to be a remote user.

Comment: Thanks, I've closed this question with your answer and asked a new question based on the information you provided: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571898/use-network-namespace-for-ssh-tunnel. I appreciate the help!