# How to assign a name to the existing anonymous network namespace

Tags: linux, namespace, network-namespaces

I have a Linux process that creates a network namespace without registering it in /run/netns. The process has also own PID namespace. The network namespace does not have a name and I can see only id of the namespace:

```
# ip netns list-id
nsid 0
nsid 1
```

Is there a possibility to assign a name to the network namespace so I can use convenient ip-netns commands to show and manage the namespace?

I have found an article [How to access an unnamed network namespace](https://gist.github.com/cfra/39f4110366fa1ae9b1bddd1b47f586a3) but it does not work for me because my process has own PID namespace so I do not see the process in the root namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no actual name existing in the low-level handling of namespaces. It's all handled by common actions or expectations done with every command in the *iproute2* suite.

Assigning a name to an existing anonymous network namespace really means: make the *iproute2* tools believe they did their usual settings when creating this network namespace.

So what is `ip netns add foo` really doing? It unshares to a new network namespace, and to keep this namespace existing even without process using it, mounts it. In the usual *nix philosophy, a namespace has an *inode* number representing a pseudo-file in the pseudo-filesystem *nsfs*. Almost no operation can be done on the file (not even read it), but it can be opened to use it as a token for namespace operations (eg `setns(2)`) and can also be mounted as a bind mount.

Alas, the link nsid is not directly usable: that's not a global value representing an other namespace, but a *local* (locally unique but recyclable and not globally unique) ID representing a *link* to an other namespace. Multiple values means: links to multiple other namespaces, twice the same value means: two links to the same other namespace.

If you have to find the other namespaces starting only from this, I invite you to check [my answer in this other Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441876/how-to-find-the-network-namespace-of-a-veth-peer-ifindex/441898#441898) where I made an answer about it. There's also a handy mapping tool available: [`plotnetcfg`](https://manpages.debian.org/plotnetcfg/plotnetcfg.8) which can map all the network namespaces. While it does know about *iproute2* methods, it doesn't appear to give a process id separately, instead it names a namespace with a PID from it when it's not "named" by *iproute2*. Redacted example (requiring [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)), run as *root*:

```
# unshare -n -- sleep 999 &
[1] 677451
#  plotnetcfg -f json | jq '.namespaces[].name'
""
[...]
"PID 268150 (systemd)"
"PID 345878 (systemd)"
[...]
"PID 677451 (sleep)"
```

Here `""` represents the initial namespace, the two `systemd` are from two LXC instances, and the `sleep` command running is also found.

To help for two common cases:

- for LXC:

  ```
  lxc-info -H -p -n containername
  ```
- for Docker:

  ```
  docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername
  ```

Once you have found by whatever method available a process in the intended network namespace, you can mimic what would do the *iproute2* tools. What they exactly do might depend on their exact version. From `strace` mine appear to do:

```
mkdir -p /run/netns
```

and then mount it over itself so it can be set as shared propagation:

```
mount --bind --make-shared /run/netns /run/netns
```

Above should only be done if not already done and only once. To have the tools do it for you (and only when needed), simply create and delete a dummy namespace:

```
ip netns add dummy && ip netns delete dummy
```

Now pick a name, for example `foo`, create an empty file and change its mode to 000 (which is not needed, but mimics *iproute2*):

```
touch /run/netns/foo
chmod 0 /run/netns/foo
```

And finally mount the process' namespace given its PID (eg `sleep` from before: 677451):

```
mount --bind /proc/677451/ns/net /run/netns/foo
```

That's it. Even if the `sleep` command ends, the namespace will now survive. All *iproute2* tools will now name it *foo*. For example if there was a *veth* interface connected to it, `ip link` would replace the link nsid's number with `foo`.

If you want to remove this network namespace, `ip netns del foo` will now do it (caveat: as usual the actual network namespace really disappears once there's no resource using it anymore, like this sleep command).

Further documentation on *iproute2*'s specific additional features along network namespaces in an [other answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471122/namespace-management-with-ip-netns-iproute2/471214#471214).

Comment: +1, looks promising, I will try later and and perhaps accept..., thanks