# How to correctly setup DNS for a macvlan in a namespace (ping IP works, ping URL does not)?

Tags: dns, routing, namespace, macvlan

I have set up macvlan in a namespace on a server. I can ping accross default namespace and macvlan namespace, i can even ping the macvlan namespace from any other client in the LAN.

But DNS is not working. What do I have to configure additionally?

```
pi@testpi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 84768sec preferred_lft 73968sec
    inet6 fe80::247e:fd3c:36d7:68f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: hostmacvlanben0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 scope global noprefixroute hostmacvlanben0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.100.174/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute hostmacvlanben0
       valid_lft 84792sec preferred_lft 73992sec
    inet6 fe80::8d5f:20a4:abba:2d1c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe98:704c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


pi@testpi:~ $ ip r
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.222 metric 202 
default via 192.168.100.1 dev hostmacvlanben0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.174 metric 204 
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.100.222 metric 202 
192.168.100.0/24 dev hostmacvlanben0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.100.174 metric 204 
192.168.100.224 dev hostmacvlanben0 scope link
```

Output for the namespace `nsben1`:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ip netns exec nsben1 ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: macvlanclient1@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.100.224/24 scope global macvlanclient1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe98:704d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ip netns exec nsben1 ip r
default via 192.168.100.1 dev macvlanclient1 
192.168.100.0/24 dev macvlanclient1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.224
```

Ping `IP` works, ping `URL` does not work:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ip netns exec nsben1 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=23.0 ms
^[[A64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=111 time=24.3 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.003/23.667/24.332/0.682 ms


pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ip netns exec nsben1 ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

`traceroute` does not give any hints:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ip netns exec nsben1 traceroute google.com
google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.100.1
```

`192.168.100.1` is the edge-router in my private LAN. I then have a cable modem from the ISP, also.

---

**Checking with `tcpdump`** on the IP of the `macvlan` namespace `nsben1` and then pinging from inside the namespace to `8.8.8.8` results in getting some answer back:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo tcpdump --interface eth0 host 192.168.100.224
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:43:45.417310 IP 192.168.100.224 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 20611, seq 1, length 64
15:43:45.440190 IP dns.google > 192.168.100.224: ICMP echo reply, id 20611, seq 1, length 64
15:43:46.418707 IP 192.168.100.224 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 20611, seq 2, length 64
15:43:46.440392 IP dns.google > 192.168.100.224: ICMP echo reply, id 20611, seq 2, length 64
```

and pinging to `www.google.com` is not getting any answer. It is pinging to `8.8.1.1` which I don't understand (note that pinging `8.8.1.1` directly is also not getting any answer):

```
15:44:13.988596 IP 192.168.100.224.45822 > 8.8.1.1.domain: 22489+ A? google.com. (28)
15:44:13.989314 IP 192.168.100.224.45822 > 8.8.1.1.domain: 25561+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
15:44:18.994541 IP 192.168.100.224.45822 > 8.8.1.1.domain: 22489+ A? google.com. (28)
15:44:18.994660 IP 192.168.100.224.45822 > 8.8.1.1.domain: 25561+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
```

---

**I used edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`** to change the nameserver from `192.168.100.1` to `8.8.8.8` and restarted the service. Now `resolv.conf` shows `nameserver 8.8.8.8` but still the behaviour is the same.

Comment: You still should add in your question your *DNS* settings. While there are different possible parts that handle it, the result is in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @A.B added this information at the bottom.

Comment: I just realized that my edgerouter seems not to have any setting set for DNS. I assume it is something that gets added to the rules somewhere when I connect the WAN of the router to the ISP modem. But I am not sure. I know I changed the DNS on my laptops to 8.8.8.8 partially and had no trouble doing this.

Comment: So from the question and your comment, you are requesting DNS from a system that doesn't provide DNS? Or did I miss something? You should do debugging using tcpdump and the dig command (install both). I wouldn't be able to give an answer on the problem.

Comment: Also see how to have a separate resolv.conf when using `ip netns exec` in this Q/A, in case that helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471122/namespace-management-with-ip-netns-iproute2

Comment: resolvconf shows `namesever 192.168.100.1` which is my edgrouter. This setting works fine in `default` namespace - regardless of how the router resolves this (probably by using the ISP modem). It is not relevant I think. The issue is why this same setting does not work from inside the new namespace `nsben1` I created - despite the `resolv.conf` pointing to the same IP and this also beeing the default route. I will look into your links and hints of course.

Comment: I just found that my `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the new namespace had `8.8.1.1` in it. I don't know why, but after a reboot it is now set to `8.8.8.8` (as the default `resolv.conf`) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **No special setup should be necessary:**

Normally, the nameserver provided in `/etc/resolv.conf` in the `default` namespace should be used in the additional namespace (`nsben1`), also.

---

### In my case this was not working.

At first I had my LAN router as nameserver, but changed this to `8.8.8.8` in an attempt to test if something was wrong from the DNS of my routers side.

Since this did not change the behaviour I investigated more and found that `sudo ip netns exec nsben1 cat /etc/resolv.conf` showed `nameserver 8.8.1.1`.

**This was wrong. Even `ping 8.8.1.1` does not give any response.**

I did not check this from the namespace `nsben1` earlier because I assumed that it simply would be the same. Changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` can be made in case of a RaspberryPi OS by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` using the line `static domain_name_servers=`.

After a reboot the namespace now also shows `8.8.8.8` and DNS works fine.